# replaceAll with lambda callback not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, java-9

I'm a bit rusty with my Java-Fu, but I ran across an issue, which I don't quite get.

I have a string `test\\"escape\"test\` that I'm trying to transform into `test\"escape"test\` (this is before string escaping).

I found this nifty `replaceAll` method with function callback, and I'm trying to remove **exactly one** backslash from all substrings beginning with backslashes and ending in a qoute ( like `\\"` to `\"`, but any other occurences of backslashes should be unmodified ).

Unfortunately I get back `test"escape"test\`, one less backslash at position 5 than expected.

Here is the code that I tried:

```java
Pattern.compile("(\\\\+\")")
   .matcher("test\\\\\"escape\\\"test\\")
   .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group().substring(1));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the string you passed in the lambda is treated as the *replacement pattern* where `\` is a special char. You need to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(mr.group().substring(1))`:

```java
String output = Pattern.compile("(\\\\+\")")
           .matcher(text)
           .replaceAll(mr -> Matcher.quoteReplacement(mr.group().substring(1)));
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GQMnyk).

You do not need to use a lambda here, you can use

```java
String text = "test\\\\\"escape\\\"test\\ that";
String output = text.replaceAll("\\\\(\\\\*\")", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
// => test\"escape"test\ that
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ieW92d) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iORBOQ/3).

The `\\(\\*")` regex matches a `\` and then captures zero or more backslashes with a `"` after them into Group 1, and the replacement is the Group 1 value.

Comment: It doesn't quite work for the second `\"` combo after escape: there should be only a single qoute.

Comment: This works, but I'm still curious what happened at the lambda function call variant.

Comment: @ZoltánSzőcs Added the original solution fix.